# Mediation using PROCESS

Tags: mediation

I've run a mediation using PROCESS.

Path a (X->M) is positive and significant (2.7, p<.0001). Path b (M->Y) is negative and significant (-.50, p=.0008). Path c' (X->Y) or the direct effect is negative and significant (-1.64, p=.009). The indirect effect is also negative and still significant (-1.36 with 95%CI of -2.29 to -.57).

How do I interpret this output? I note the direct effect: higher values of X are associated with lower values of Y. But are the expected differences  mediated by the M? Or what I'm dealing with here is suppression because the indirect effect is -1.36, lower in absolute value than -1.64?

It is a tricky one because the direction is expected, based on the direction of the scales... High X is bad and would be related to low Y (hence negative direct effect). High X is bad and can be expected to be related to high M (positive effect above). High M can be expected to be related to low Y (negative effect above).

Comment: I think you're confusing total effect: direct+indirect effect with the direct effect. You can interpret the model exactly as you have above. What this means is that conditioning on X will have the greatest impact on managing Y both through its direct effect and the indirect effect via M, provided the appropriate causal assumptions are met. The relative magnitude of the direct and indirect effects are just incidental. If the direct effect is close to 0, the implications are to treat or condition on the X or the M.

Comment: Thank you. The total effect (c) in this example is even higher, -3.00 (p<.0001). I've labelled them as c' and c, I might change the labeling to decrease confusion. Hopefully I'm not confusing them...? Could you please expand on that to make sure I'm not getting this wrong? Also if I understand right what you are saying: it is not supression, but both direct and indirect effects and that is fine; but how do I interpret the fact that the a*b indirect effect is slightly lower than the direct (c) effect, albeit significant?